# Local site within Dropbox using IIS

Tags: iis, dropbox

I am trying to have my local website within dropbox using IIS. When I add the dropbox directory I get the error:   The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path.

I am admin and have allowed all access to the dropbox folder.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should add IIS user account to the list of users who are allowed to view/read the files. IIS usually runs via separate user account for security reasons.
This is done the following way:

1. Right-click on your site folder in Dropbox
2. Select "Security"
3. Click "Add"
4. Find IUSR user and/or IIS_IUSRS group
5. Add them both (or one, if only one is present) and assign them read permissions
6. Try adding your site folder again.

This should fix the issue.